# How to do jQuery on 'load' in v1.6 (before "on" was introduced)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I have an SVG object in the body of my HTML

```
<object id="svg-map" type="image/svg+xml" data="documents/map.svg">Your browser does not support SVGs</object>
```

I've tried several different ways of firing a function when the object has loaded. Using the onload attribute on the object element works (yuck!). Using JS addEventListener works. But using jQuery on load doesn't work.

```
//Method 2: FAIL (v1.6)
$("#svg-map").on("load", function() {
   alert("loaded2");
});
//Method 3: FAIL (v1.6)
$("#svg-map").load(function() {
   alert("loaded3");
});
//Method 4: SUCCESS
$("#svg-map")[0].addEventListener("load", function() {
   alert("loaded4");
});
```

I've been warned about mixing native javascript event handlers with jquery, but I'm not sure why. Is there any reason I shouldn't use method 4 above?

Is there a way of doing this with jQuery in version 1.6?

Comment: That link doesn't explain your problem. All it is saying is that if an event handler on a child does not cancel propagation, then any event handlers (of the appropriate type) on it's parent will then be fired. And so on up through all the ancestors.

Comment: Ah, thank you! Makes much more sense now - removed from question to avoid further comments.

Comment: have you tried `.load()` http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: @chiliNUT I tried `.load()` as shown in method 3.

Answer (score 0):

I remember using .bind and .delegate before jumping into .on
Have you tried them?

`.bind("load", function() {`
`.delegate("load", function() {`

Comment: Thanks Raphael, I've been using delegate for `hover`, `mouseenter`, `mousemove` and `mouseleave` events but apparently that doesn't work with `load` events because they don't "bubble".